# Ocaml Pattern Matching User Defined Type

Tags: types, functional-programming, ocaml

I am trying to write a function which can either return an int or a string, based on the result of a call to a function `baz`.

```
type 'a foo = OK of 'a | Error of string

let bar (e) : int foo =
    match baz e with
    | OK (_) -> 1
    | Error s -> s
```

However, I get this error message when compiling:

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         int foo
Command exited with code 2.
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Here's the actual snippet of code I'm dealing with:

```
type 'a error = | OK of 'a | Error of string

type typing_judgement = subst*expr*texpr


let rec infer' (e:expr) (n:int): (int*typing_judgement) error =
    match e with
    | _ -> failwith "infer': undefined"


let infer_type (AProg e) =
    match infer' e 0 with
    | OK (_, tj) -> string_of_typing_judgement tj
    | Error s -> "Error! "^ s
```

The end goal here is a type inference engine, so as I can tell infer_type will be given an expression, which will be passed to infer' (which I will have to implement). I've never worked with Ocaml before and I'm just trying to get this to compile before I even attempt to implement these functions.

Comment: You can't return either just an int or a string. You'll have to wrap it in a variant, which is of course what you already have. The direct cause of the error, however, is that you specify `int foo` as the return type, when it's actually the argument type. There's really not much that makes sense about the code you've written. Perhaps if you provide a bit more context it would be possible to understand what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I need to make a type inference engine and have literally never worked with Ocaml before lol. I made an edit to the post with the actual code I'm working with

Comment: I don't see what the issue is with your actual code. If `bar` is supposed to represent `infer_type`, the latter returns a `string` in each branch, so no problem there.

Comment: so if you compile that code it complains that ```string_of_typing_judgement``` is undefined, so I took it out temporarily. You're saying taking that out could be causing the issue, since when it's in both branches return a string? I don't really understand how pattern matching works, is it that ```string_of_typing_judgement``` takes on the value of whatever the wildcard matched? And if so, then it will resolve to a string applied to a typing_judgement, which doesn't make sense to me. (Again, sorry for the ignorant questions, I have no experience with Ocaml whatsoever).

Comment: `string_of_typing_judgement` is used as a function here, being given a `typing_judgement` (`tj`). And by the name of it I'd say it's supposed to transform the `typing_judgement` into a `string`, which happens to work out well since the other branch returns a string as well. If the function is undefined, I guess that means you're supposed to implement it yourself. You also might want to pick up a book on the language, because these are pretty basic language concepts and you only seem to confuse yourself more by making flawed assumptions about them.

Comment: Right, okay that makes perfect sense. My brain saw "string_of" and for some reason I assumed this meant "string coming from a typing judgement". Yes I really should read up on this more, I thought I understood the core concept but perhaps not. Thank you for your patience and explanations!

Comment: No problem :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

From your initial code, it looks like the function wants to be:

```
let bar e =
```

(In general, let OCaml infer the type of e) That said, when you get a result back of Ok or Error, this is the variant you're looking for (as glennsl says).  At that point, you can report the Error or return some result.  For example:

```
let bar e =
    match baz e with
    | Ok _ -> ()
    | Error s ->
        let () = prerr_endline ("Error: " ^ s) in
        exit 1
```

The Ok case returns void in my example, since your code didn't seem concerned about the contents of Ok, but you could simply return that instead:

```
| Ok result -> result
```

Again, OCaml will infer all the types, so there's no need to be explicit like you would be in C/C++.

As to the actual code: failwith will throw an exception.  Apart from the "infer" function cleanup, "infer_type" could look something like this:

```
let infer_type expr =
    try string_of_typing_judgment @@ infer expr
    with Failure msg -> 
        let () = prerr_endline ("Infer failed with: " ^ msg) in
        exit 1
```

The @@ is just a handy operator that avoids the need for parentheses.  It means the same as:

```
string_of_typing_judgment (infer expr)
```

But the overall paradigm, here, when using failwith, is exception handling.  If you're expecting an exception, use the "try/with" syntax.

Finally, I'd recommend running through a couple of quickstart tutorials on OCaml before starting your project.  A lot of this will get cleared up pretty quickly once you have some worked examples.